# Отложенные задачи

Tags: android

Есть в Андроиде такая функция, как отложенное выполнение задачи?

Идея в чем:

Метод `void doResult(int id)` получает `id` какого-то действия, производит часть этого действия (через `switch` отображает текст, делает подсчеты и определяет метод, который должен быть следующим (условно каждый раз разный)) и ждет пока пользователь нажмет на кнопку - дает время осмыслить произошедшее.

При нажатии на кнопку происходит переход в нужный метод и выполняются новые действия (инфа с UI сбрасывается). То есть что-то типа "паузы".

Или как вообще лучше реализовать подобное поведение? 
Есть идея реализовать это, разбив на два switch'а, но возможно есть способ проще.

Comment: а почему не сделать просто два отдельных метода? А нужные между методами данные передавать маленьким классом.

Comment: вопрос в том, предусмотрена ли в Аднроид такая функция? Два свича/метода то сделать можно :)

Comment: Конечно в андроид есть выполнение действия по расписанию. Иначе, как бы работал будильник)

За него отвечает класс AlarmManager.
Он выполняет произвольный PendingIntent(как только наступит установленное время).
Который можно поймать в onReceive.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example

Comment: pending intent, точно! ) похоже то, что надо, спасибо :)